# XML to CMIS returns no data

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, cmis

For a project i need to create a XSLT file which transform XML files to CMIS.

When i test the transformation through a XSLT Editor (like w3schools) it returns all the data but when i use the XSLT file inside my project it returns no data at all.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Metadata schemaUri="http://www.nationaalarchief.nl/ToPX/v2.3">
    <Content>
        <ToPX xmlns="http://www.nationaalarchief.nl/ToPX/v2.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <aggregatie>
                <identificatiekenmerk>Test</identificatiekenmerk>
                <aggregatieniveau>Test</aggregatieniveau>
                <naam>Test</naam>
                <omschrijving>Test</omschrijving>
                <plaats>Test</plaats>
                <eventGeschiedenis>
                    <datumOfPeriode>
                        <periode>
                            <begin>
                                <datum>2023-01-01</datum>
                            </begin>
                                            <eind>
                                                    <datum>2023-12-31</datum>
                            </eind>
                        </periode>
                    </datumOfPeriode>
                                <type>Test</type>
                                <verantwoordelijkeFunctionaris>Test</verantwoordelijkeFunctionaris>
                </eventGeschiedenis>
            </aggregatie>
        </ToPX>
    </Content>
</Metadata>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ToPX="http://www.nationaalarchief.nl/ToPX/v2.3" exclude-result-prefixes="ToPX">
    <xsl:template match="//ToPX:aggregatie">
        <item>
            <name>Identificatiekenmerk</name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:identificatiekenmerk" />
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Aggregatieniveau</name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:aggregatieniveau"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Naam</name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:naam"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Omschrijving</name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:omschrijving"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Plaats</name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:plaats"/>
        </item>
        <group>
            <title>Kenmerken</title>
            <item>
                <name>Begindatum:</name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:eventGeschiedenis/ToPX:datumOfPeriode/ToPX:periode/ToPX:begin/ToPX:datum"/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <name>Einddatum:</name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:eventGeschiedenis/ToPX:datumOfPeriode/ToPX:periode/ToPX:eind/ToPX:datum"/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <name>Type</name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:eventGeschiedenis/ToPX:type"/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <name>Verantwoordelijke functionaris</name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ToPX:eventGeschiedenis/ToPX:verantwoordelijkeFunctionaris"/>
            </item>
        </group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried a lot of different things but i'am stuck. I cannot get the data inside my project. It should be nice if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Which processor are you using (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153)?

Comment: Do note that your stylesheet  is designed to return an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document with a single root element. Perhaps that's the cause of the problem?